# Difference between Selenium Grid2, Selenium Grid, and Remote webdriver

Tags: selenium-rc, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and need your help to understand the difference between Grid2, Grid, and remoteWebDriver. I like the consept behind Selenium Grid, but notice there is Grid2 using Selenium2. Then heard about RemoteWebDriver and now I'm not sure how they are related and which one is better to implement original selenium Grid concept.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Basically:

Grid 2 is the new version of Grid, which works with the new WebDriver-Backed Selenium (Selenium 2).

The term "Selenium" is often used interchangeably with "WebDriver", but they are not the same thing; Selenium is powered by WebDriver. Selenium provides a more robust feature set, and while you can accomplish the same things with WebDriver, Selenium takes care of the details for some of the more complex operations.

RemoteWebDriver interacts with the Grid to run tests across multiple machines or VMs.
In other words, you write your tests with the RemoteWebDriver (or with Selenium 2), and then you can plug them into the grid.